# how to retrieve data based on particuler id

Tags: grails, groovy

```
def index(Integer max) {
    params.max = Math.min(params.max ? params.int('max') : 5, 100)
    respond Chit.list(params), model:[chitInstanceCount: Chit.count()]
}
```

This is my show view from controller and i need to fetch specific data based on ID.

Answer (score -1):

```
def index(Integer max) {
        params.max = Math.min(params.max ? params.int('max') : 5, 100)
        def c=Chit.findAllById(1) // 1 will your id e.g params?.id
        respond c, model:[chitInstanceCount: Chit.count()]
        }
```

Where `c` return list of records with id 1

If you have single record by id and is primary key then simply you can do by using get

```
respond Chit.get(id)
```

Comment: Thanks @Rahul, i have one more doubt , If I Have More Records How can i Fetch based On Id

Comment: @maheshsiripuram i have already given both scenarios in answer i.e. `def c=Chit.findAllById(1)`

Comment: Thanks alot @Rahul Mahadik

Answer (score -1):

Actually you SHOULD use a `show()` action to show a data record based on id. The scaffolded verion looks like that:

```
def show( String id ){
  respond Chit.get( id )
}
```